# Interpretation and usage of негоже

Tags: словоупотребление

I recently came across this sentence:

> В любом случае клейми́ть целую нацию из-за частных случаев **негоже**.

However, I'm having a hard time finding any concrete information on the actual meaning of негоже, and it's register - is it colloquial, formal, archaic, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*Негоже*" (from "негожий" / "негодный" / "unfit" / "useless") means "не следует" (ought not), i.e. a very strong "advice" not to do something. It is typically used as a predicative.

It's colloquial but rather obsolete. Most often such words are to be found in a book within character's direct speech. But I wouldn't say it's archaic, as it's still spoken from time to time (just as many other "old" words in Russian language), sometimes also idiomatic, e.g.: "возьми, убоже, что нам негоже".

> I'm having a hard time finding any concrete information

I suggest you use [this dictionary](http://feb-web.ru/feb/mas/mas-abc/default.asp).

Comment: So as a comment in a social media site, this is kind of tongue-in-cheek?

Comment: @CocoPop Well, not necessary, at least in the sense of "totally not serious". It is rather a joke, yes, but as it is said, в каждой шутке есть доля шутки. That should heavily depend upon the context, but I'd rather expect this word to be used to sweeten the pill or something.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant) The original comment was followed by two smileys. We often use archaic words and expressions like this in English, in a tongue-in-cheek way.

Comment: Well, after two up-styled (напыщенных) words In a row - клеймить, нацию - use of "негоже" looks rather natural. And no smileys. (Remember that Russians don't smile;))

Comment: @Matt This phrase is not a joke. It says that it's unacceptable to blame the whole nation for the behavior of several people. No more, no less. "Негоже" is a neutral word. It gives no subjective evaluation of the action. Its intent is to softly remark that something is unacceptable.

Answer (score 4):

**Негоже** replaces the phrase *(это) никуда не годится* and means '**it's not the thing to do**'. Works as a predicative adverb here. It is an outdated, bookish word but sometimes it is used for sounding less formal - instead of words like *неприемлемо*, *недопустимо* etc.

Comment: @ CocoPop Is the expression 'not the done thing' (which I suggested) out of usage now or maybe the context is somehow wrong for it?

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+the+done+thing
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-the-done-thing

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess they say that in England. I changed it here because I'd never heard that expression before and I like to edit the answers to my question so that they make sense to me if I read them at some point in the future again. I hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Literary and rather archaic. From "не годится".